# Calculating volume of an object given x y z parameters

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing, foreach

Basically I am building a barcode for a company and in a certain part of the barcode string I need to calculate the volume of an orders item in cubic meters. The barcode sequence looks like: ddxxxx, where the sequence of digits supplied is interpreted as dd.xxxx cubic metres and has a maximum value of 99.9999 cubic metres.
If this is unknown, its set to 000000
The data type is numeric and is 6 digits, and each digit must be numeric characters ie. 0,1,2,3 ... , 9.

This is the code I have so far:

```
public double volumeCalculation(Order order) {
  double totalVolume = 0;

  foreach (var item in order.ShipOrders) {
    var dims = item.Dimensions.Replace(" ", "").Split('X');

    var x = double.Parse(dims[0]) / 100;
    var y = double.Parse(dims[1]) / 100;
    var z = double.Parse(dims[2]) / 100;

    var vol = (x * y * z);

    totalVolume += vol;
  }

  return totalVolume;
}
```

I know that I need to use Math.Truncate or string.Format in order to handle this operation, but i'm having difficulty implementing it. Any help with this would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't actually said what problem you are experiencing.

Comment: If what you want to do is convert totalVolume into a string in the format that you require then state that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for *formatting*, "`00.0000`" - *two* digits before and *four* digits after the decimal point.

```
   // static: you don't want "this" in the method
   // String: you want a String, not double, right?
   public static String volumeCalculation(Order order) { 
     // Since method is public one, validate input
     if (null == order)
       throw new ArgumentNullException("order");

     // I suggest using Linq here
     return Order.ShipOrders
       .Select(line => line.Split('X'))
       .Select(items => items
         .Select(item => double.Parse(item) / 100.0)
         .Aggregate((x, s) => x * s))
       .Sum()
       .ToString("00.0000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) // <- formatting
       .Replace(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator, "");
   }
```

Comment: @afrogonabike: technically, `'.'` is quite enough, but safier choice is `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` - what if, say, *C# v 123.0* will change `'.'` for `'='` ;)

Comment: Ok true, deleted my comment as I worked this out myself! Belt and braces Thanks

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to format total volume

```
var barCodeString = totalVolume.ToString("00.0000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace(".","");
```